# Change of entropy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

An ideal gas is heated in a **constant pressure** process such that its **final temperature** is twice the
**initial temperature**, the corresponding **entropy** change in ideal gas is  **$\Delta S$**. If the same mass of **ideal gas**
with same initial state would have been heated in a **constant volume** process such that its **final
temperature** would be twice the **initial temperature**, the corresponding **entropy change** in ideal gas would
be greater or less than the **entropy change** in the first case?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Please consider adding equations and explain what you have done to try to solve the problem so far.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!